# webpack config missing in vuejs

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

My vuejs app's package.json looks like

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "vue_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "lint-staged": "^6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@vue/app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ]
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.vue": [
      "vue-cli-service lint",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Upon building the vue app, it generates an index.html file while looks like,

`dist/index.html`

```
<body>
    <noscript><strong>We're sorry but vue_app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div
        id=app></div>
        <script type=text/javascript>
            (function(r){var n=window["webpackJsonp"];window["webpackJsonp"]=function(e,u,c){for(var i,f,p,l=0,a=[];l<e.length;l++)f=e[l],t[f]&&a.push(t[f][0]),t[f]=0;for(i in u)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(u,i)&&(r[i]=u[i]);n&&n(e,u,c);while(a.length)a.shift()();if(c)for(l=0;l<c.length;l++)p=o(o.s=c[l]);return p};var e={},t={2:0};function o(n){if(e[n])return e[n].exports;var t=e[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return r[n].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,o),t.l=!0,t.exports}o.m=r,o.c=e,o.d=function(r,n,e){o.o(r,n)||Object.defineProperty(r,n,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},o.n=function(r){var n=r&&r.__esModule?function(){return r["default"]}:function(){return r};return o.d(n,"a",n),n},o.o=function(r,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(r,n)},o.p="/",o.oe=function(r){throw console.error(r),r}})([]);
//# sourceMappingURL=/js/manifest.bb41d6d8.js.map
        </script>
        <script type=text/javascript src=/js/vendor.be88a6a7.js></script>
        <script type=text/javascript src=/js/app.5edcb6c7.js></script>
</body>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= webpackConfig.output.publicPath %>favicon.ico">
    <title>Flask + Vue.js Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but vue_app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

On running static files are failed to get fetched , ie. `/js/vendor.be88a6a7.js` returns 404 but it can be fetched by calling `/static/js/vendor.be88a6a7.js` url. So I have to prepend `/static` to all the static url paths. But I don't find any webpack.conf file located on that directory.

[source code](https://github.com/gtalarico/flask-vuejs-template/tree/master/app/client/vue_app)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In vue cli 3 the webpack config file is generated dynamically at runtime. It has been abstracted away. That is the reason you don't see a webpack config file.

You can find the webpack config file here:

```
<projectRoot>/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js
```

This is the file that is dynamically resolved.

The `output.publiPath` is `/` by default in the webpack config file. If you want to check want is webpack config file looks like you can use `vue inspect` command in your command line or via `vue ui` -> click Tasks -> click inspect. It prints out a serialized format only meant for inspection of the config file.

But if you want to configure the webpack config you can make use of the `vue.config.js` file.

If you do not have `vue.config.js` file, then create it in root of your project.

Then add the following:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            publicPath: '/static/'
        }
    }
}
```

Resources:

- [Vue-Cli 3 docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/docs)
- [Configuring Webpack](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/docs/config#configurewebpack)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know "Configuring Webpack" link is dead.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!. No more no less