# JavaScript not enabled error when launching VueJS app

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I created a VueJS app and I'm getting the following error when I look at the source code in the web browser:

```
<noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but pay-loader doesn't work properly     without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
```

I tried a creating a vue.config.js file in the root directory as suggested here :

[webpack config missing in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304066/webpack-config-missing-in-vuejs)

This didn't work for me,  how can fix this issue?

I'm using vue version 3.0.0-rc.5

Thanks

Comment: try to update to the vue-cli 3.

Comment: which browser is it?

Comment: You are using a pre-release version of the `@vue/cli`, upgrade to a stable version

Comment: Updating to vue-cli3 fixed it. Thanks @roliroli

Comment: Glad to read that I helped you. :)

Comment: Guys please help: @vue/cli 4.0.5 still the same issue. Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)